# SQL: Select to add an extra **non-null** column?

Tags: sql, select

I have an SQL table with the following columns:

```
title, author, genre, rating
```

Is it possible to write `select` that will add to output an extra **non-null** column `src` that has a default value "online" for every input record? Such as:

```
select 'online' as src, title, author, genre, rating from table;
```

So a resulting record should have the following format:

```
src, title, author, genre, rating
```

where src = "online" for every output record

Comment: `select 'online' as src, title, author, genre, rating from table;` looks fine. What exactly is your problem? What happened when you tried? Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work exactly as you wrote

```
select 'online' as src, title, author, genre, rating from table;
```

Comment: Yes, it works, sorry for confusion. I had a syntax error in a very complicated `select` in `sqoop` request to import data from SQL DB to Hadoop HDFS.